# How to save the content of an imageView to internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like someone to tell me a method of how to save the contents of an imageView to internal storage as I am not quite sure how to do it and it is not like I know much about kotlin as I am learning

Any help is appreciated from the heart

This is the method I am using:

```
private fun imageRandomFun() {
        val quest1 = "https://proxxcraft.com/"
        Picasso.get().load(quest1).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(memeRandomView)
        Picasso.get().isLoggingEnabled = true
    }

private fun saveImageToStore() {
        val externalStoreState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
        if (externalStoreState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            val storeDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString()
            val file = File(storeDirectory, "testimage.jpg")
            try {
                val stream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                var drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireActivity(), R.drawable.logo)
                var bitmap = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
                stream.flush()
                stream.close()
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "Imagen gaurdada ${Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)}",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "ASDASDA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly did you put an image into the `ImageView` originally? For example, if you used an image-loading library, would you be better served tying into that to save a copy of the source image to a separate file?

Comment: Done, I already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you used the `getExternalStorageState ()` method to get your directory in this line:

```
var storeDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
```

according to the official documentation it

> Returns the current state of the primary shared / external storage
> media

So try with this :

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone)
        val storeDirectory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) // DCIM folder 
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $storeDirectory")
        val file = File(storeDirectory, "testimage.jpg")
        val stream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        val drawable = image.drawable
        val bitmap = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
        stream.close()
    }
}
```

If you have added the right permission and grants it should work And you'll find the images in the DCIM folder

Comment: You mean `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: Ok let me try and I'll tell you what happens

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work to change it

Comment: In fact it does not give an error but when I press the button it does nothing and the console does not say anything either and if you ask whether to call the function `saveImageToStore ()` to the button

Comment: please add this    `Log.e("error", "onCreate: ",e )` in the catch{} instruction to see the given error

Comment: The project does not start as it gives an error in the `image must not be null `caused by `val drawable = image.drawable`

Comment: Can't cast null drawable?

Comment: Does not allow compilation as it detects that the drawable is null

Comment: yes but use your images  like your code. i give you an example how i can get content of image and i save it  in phone storage